# JAVA regarding a particular method

Tags: java

I just got back my Java test paper and there is one question that has been bugging me.

There was a question:

What is the output of the following program?

```
public class Swap {
    public static void swap(int[] a){
        int temp = a[1];
        a[1] = a[0];
        a[0] = temp;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] x = {5,3};
        swap(x);
        System.out.println("x[0]:" + x[0] + " x[1]:" + x[1]);
    }
}
```

The thought that first came to my mind was that this was a trick question. Since the swap method return type was void, I thought that it had no effect on the int[] x array. My answer was x[0]:5 x[1]:3. I was almost certain that I got the correct answer and when I saw that I had been marked wrong, I got confused. I went to try out the actual code on NetBeans and realized that the values in the array actually got swapped! I then went on to test if this was the case for String. I typed in a similar but different code:

```
public class Switch {
    public static void switch(String s){
        s = "GOODBYE";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String x = "HELLO";
        switch(x);
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

The output still printed HELLO instead of GOODBYE. Now my question is why does the method not change the String but it changes the values inside an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java - "References to Objects are passed by value".

```
public class Swap {
    public static void swap(int[] a){  // now a = x --> {5,3}
        int temp = a[1]; 
        a[1] = a[0];     // swapping a[0] and a[1] in this and next step.
        a[0] = temp;
// NOW only a[] goes out of scope but since both x and a were pointing to the "same" object {5,3}, the changes made by a will be reflected in x i.e, in the main method.
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] x = {5,3}; // here - x is a reference that points to an array {5,3}
        swap(x);   
        System.out.println("x[0]:" + x[0] + " x[1]:" + x[1]);
    }
}
```

And,

```
public class Switch {
    public static void switch(String s){ // now s=x="Hello"
        s = "GOODBYE";   //here x="hello" , s ="GOODBYE"  i.e, you are changing "s" to point to a different String i.e, "GOODBYE", but "x" still points to "Hello"
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String x = "HELLO";
        switch(x);
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh! That made sense. Thanks for the answer~ Finally able to get this puzzle out of my head.

Answer (score 2):

Because writing `s = "GOODBYE";` just points `s` to a different String.  It doesn't change the value of the original String.

Whereas writing `a[0] = something;` or `a[1] = something;` is actually messing around with the array referenced by `a`, but not pointing `a` to a different array.